# How to get Pytest to NOT skip tests in a module when one test fails

Tags: pytest

In seems the default behavior of pytest, if a test in a module fails because of an assert which failed, all the remaining tests are skipped. Is there a way to prevent this so that the following tests in that module after the failed test are executed. Apart from splitting the tests up in separate modules, I can see no other way.
Version of pytest is 4.6.4, python version is 2.7.15

Comment: The standard behavior of a pytest is to pass all the tests in the module, regardless of which ones fell. What you described is not standard pytest behavior.
Maybe you run it with the argument -x? http://pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#stopping-after-the-first-or-n-failures

If not, then provide an example code and a command on how you run pytest

Comment: Please check whether you have a custom `pytest.ini` config file or `[tool:pytest]` section in the `setup.cfg`, is there any custom configuration listed? Also, it may be some plugin silently modifying the test execution. Run e.g. `pytest --collect-only | grep plugins` and uninstall the plugins listed.

Comment: You can modify pytest assertion behavior using pytest hooks. but there is no command line option to do what you mentioned.